# It is possible to get the screen position of a row when it's clicked?

Tags: android, dialog, adapter, android-adapter, android-dialog

It is possible to get the screen position, inside of the adapter, of a specific row when it is clicked? What i want is to use a dialog with dim background but I want it to appear below the row that was clicked. Popupwindow does that by default but i cannot dim the background, that's why I am trying to use the dialog instead.

Comment: Are you using AlertDialog.Builder to submit the adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the screen position of a view with these functions:

```
View.getLocationOnScreen()
getLocationInWindow()
```

but trying to position a dialog at a certain position of the screen is probably a bad idea, let the system handle that.